# Virtual Category not working when using custom product attribute text field

Tags: magento2, admin

When searching with custom attribute, Virtual Category not working. It is not searching related to that. In which file we need to change for this.

[image]

Comment: what's a virtual category?

Comment: @Marius Catalog > Categories > Virtual Category updated with screenshot plz check

Comment: is this a standard magento feature? I haven't seen it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you using Elasticsuite? Virtual category is something like category of search results. So you set your parameters and search is done and shown in category. But for search to be done, you need to make attribute that is searchable. Check if your attribute is searchable. If not, it does not count for virtual category search. After making it searchable, do full reindex.

Comment: In product >attribute i verified it is serachble only

Comment: What scope that attribute have?

Comment: store view is there

Comment: If I remember correct, it should be global.

Comment: store view not work? need to change to global?

Comment: Yes, attribute should be global scope.